# C | Compare char * with char

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have this code:

```
const char *linesep = "\n";
char buffer[10];
buffer[0] = 'L';
```

How can I check linesep and buffer[0] are the same? Like using strcmp.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You want to compare the single char in `buffer[0]` with the single char you find at the start of  the string pointed to by `linesep`, i.e. `buffer[0]==*linesep` ? This is what your question reads like. Is it that simple? If not, you need to explain quite a lot more.

Comment: buffer[0] is type of char, and linesep is type of char*, and you can not compare them. you may compare linesep with buffer

Comment: ^^.. which would be pointless, as  they are clearly different,

Comment: I want to check if buffer[i] == linesep. For example buffer[i] == '\n' and linesep = "\n". In this case they are equal.

Comment: I still have exactly the same question... Maybe you could explain why you seem to store a single reference character in a 0-terminated string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to compare a `char` to a `char` you could simply do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    const char *linesep = "\n";
    char buffer[10];
    buffer[0] = 'L';
    printf("%s", linesep[0] == buffer[0] ? "same" : "not same");
    return 0;
}
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/kUqkRC